# How to add image inside border and animate the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I want to add the image inside div border and then animate the image. **Please see below picture for better understanding.**

[image]

I also added video link for border animation, Hope it will help to understand this question.

[Border animation video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8Ub4OTQ9BZjR2Z5N3J0bU1oeVE/view?usp=sharing)

Please share if there anything that can help me to get the result any slider, library etc.

Thanks